# SQL Update conservating actual data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Column named 'Complete name'
I need to update people with any last name 'Smiht' to 'Smith' without losing the name and the second last name.

For example, now I have:

```
John Smiht G.

Sarah Connor Smiht

John Ford Connor

James Smiht Ford
```

And the result of update has to be the same data but with Smiht being replaced to Smith:

```
John Smith G.

Sarah Connor Smith

John Ford Connor

James Smith Ford
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add sample data, showing us what your table would look like before and after the update?

Comment: ok, I added the sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic method is something like this:

```
update t
    set CompleteName = replace(CompleteName, ' Smiht', ' Smith'
    where CompleteName like '% Smiht%';
```

Comment: What would be more efficient, to update the entire data, or to use that where clause with `LIKE` ?

Comment: @sagi . . . Generally, using the `where` clause will be more efficient.  Attempts to update -- even if there are no changes -- can incur overhead.